# How to get INNER Join Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I have three tables PurchaseDetails, SalesDetails and ProductMaster. 
I have a product in there master P0001

How can I join this table in sql2008 to get profit and loss reports

I have written this code I'm not getting why its showing four time...

```
SELECT PM.product_id,
       PM.product_name,
       PM.company_name,
       PM.opening_stock,

  (SELECT SUM(CAST(qty AS decimal(18, 0))) AS [Purchase Stock ]
   FROM Purchase_Order_Details) AS [Purchase Stock ],
       CAST(CONVERT(decimal(18, 0), PM.opening_stock) +
              (SELECT SUM(CAST(qty AS decimal(18, 0))) AS [Purchase Stock ]
               FROM Purchase_Order_Details AS Purchase_Order_Details_1) AS decimal(18, 0)) AS [Total Purchase Stock],
       CAST(CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), PM.opening_stock) * CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), PM.rate) + CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), PO.net_amount) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS [Total Purchase Cost],

  (SELECT SUM(CAST(qty AS decimal(18, 0))) AS [Purchase Stock ]
   FROM Order_Details) AS [Sales Stock ], PM.closing_stock AS [Closing Stock], O.net_amount AS [Sales Cost]
FROM Purchase_Order_Details AS POD
INNER JOIN Purchase_Order AS PO ON POD.pdoc_id = PO.pdoc_id
INNER JOIN Product_Master AS PM
INNER JOIN Order_Details AS OD ON PM.product_id = OD.product_id
INNER JOIN Ordered AS O ON OD.doc_id = O.doc_id ON POD.product_id = PM.product_id
```

Output

[image]

can any one solve this problem ?

Comment: Basic SQL debugging - change your `SELECT` clause to a `SELECT *` and then use your eyeballs to work out which columns actually contain different data. That should then inform you on which `JOIN`s are producing multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have no conditions on the join to the Product_Master table, so you will get all rows from that table. That is, all product_master rows for all other rows. That should explain it. Try adding join conditions to the table(s) that it relates to.

```
    INNER JOIN Product_Master AS PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Why below statement is empty ? Is there any significance of it ??

Instead of using Purchase_Order_Details try to use Product_Master first

```
INNER JOIN Product_Master AS PM
```

Comment: I have build this by system automatic don't know why this happen could you explain me?

Comment: How did you build it? In Management Studio? Perhaps there is no foreign key defined in the database. Then you have to add the join condition manually.